# How to format header WWW-Authenticate when authentication fails

Tags: http, rest, authentication

I'm implementing a REST API that also provides functionality for authenticating users. Authentication requires an user to send a POST request with the following data in the body:

```
{
  "userOrEmail": "spook",
  "passowrd": "Test1234"
}
```

If the username and password match, the user gets back a token from the server, while if they don't, the server returns 401 Unauthorized, with the following header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Credentials realm="http://localhost:9000/auth/users/credentials"
```

Is that header acceptable? `realm` contains the location where the user can try to authenticate again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be acceptable, but maybe not optimal except under very specific conditions.  From [RFC1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11):

> The realm value (case-sensitive), in combination with the canonical root URL of the server being accessed, defines the protection space. These realms allow the protected resources on a server to be partitioned into a set of protection spaces, each with its own authentication scheme and/or authorization database. The realm value is a string, generally assigned by the origin server, which may have additional semantics specific to the authentication scheme.

So, you can, but I might be paranoid about multiple applications using the same authentication and inadvertently cross-authenticating if they were to share the same realm name.  Better would be to isolate the realm by application, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Yes... I saw RFC1945 too. So it would be better something like this? WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api". I find a bit difficult to identify an appropriate value for realm...

Comment: My understanding is that the tradition is your application's name, so it's not confused by anybody else on your server.  To combine your idea, you might be able to stuff the application name into that URL and get (something like) the best of both worlds.

Comment: Very last question... the URL should be absolute or relative to the canonical root URL of the server being accessed as stated by RFC1945?

Comment: The RFC doesn't seem to care.  For your notification purposes, then, I'd say to use the whole URL.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not acceptable.

a) There is no authentication scheme called "credentials".

b) The purpose of the "realm" parameter is different.